Combinatorial problem of selecting objects in a straight line from two group with each group of similar kind objects

We have $10$ similar objects of one kind and $7$ similar objects of another kind. Compute the number of ways to arrange $5$ from these total ($10 + 7$) objects into a straight line.

I am not sure about my approach and the final answer, hence wanted to validate the same through experts here.
My Solution is :
Let   be the number of objects chosen from the first kind (out of 10), and  5 −  be the number of objects chosen from the second kind (out of 7)
Then for x = 0, we select 0 objects from first type in 1 way and 5 objects from 2nd type in 1 way (since objects within each group are identical). Therefore, ways to distribute is 1
For x = 1, we select 1 object from first type in 1 way and 4 objects from 2nd type in 1 way. Now post selection, number of ways to distribute is 5!/1! 4! ways = 5 ways
For x = 2, we select 2 object from first type in 1 way and 3 objects from 2nd type in 1 way. Now post selection, number of ways to distribute is 5!/2! 3! ways = 10 ways
For x = 3, we select  object from first type in 1 way and 2 objects from 2nd type in 1 way. Now post selection, number of ways to distribute is 5!/3! 2! ways = 10 ways
For x = 4, we select  object from first type in 4 way and 1 objects from 2nd type in 1 way. Now post selection, number of ways to distribute is 5!/4! 1! ways = 5 ways
Then for x = 5, we select 5 objects from first type in 1 way and 0 objects from 2nd type in 1 way. Therefore, ways to distribute is 1
Total distribution = 1 + 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 1 = 32

Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? As a hint: you have enough of both types of objects to form the entire line, so all you really need to worry about is what order the types appear.

I have posted my solution above, I am not sure if my approach and the final answer are correct

Your solution looks great! A simpler way: because each type has $\ge 5$ indistinguishable items, you can just pick, for each spot in the line, which of the two types goes in that spot. This is $2^5 = 32$, just as you calculated.

@K.Jiang If, say there was $4$ instead of $7$ objects, would there be $2^4$ ways to fill the $5$ slots?

@Gwen No. If there are $10$ objects of one type and $4$ objects of another, to be put into a line of $5$ items, you can follow Tiger's approach, but this time the case where we take $5$ items of the second type is not included. So there are $32 - 1 = 31$ possibilities. You can also see the approach in the answer.


As  explained by K. Jiang, as there are are sufficient numbers of both types of objects, the answer for your original problem is simply $2^5$

When the the numbers aren't sufficient in one or more categories, e.g. in your supplementary question in comments, where category B has only $4$ available, but you want a total of $5$, the formula becomes
$${5!}\left[\frac{1!}{5!0!} + \frac{1!}{4!1!} + \frac{1!}{3!2!} + \frac{1!}{2!3!} + \frac{1!}{1!4!}
\right] = 31$$


This formula can be extended for any number of types, some types having sufficient numbers, and some havng shortages

Does the word straight line hold any meaning here?

@Tiger: The intention could have been put more explicitly, as  arrangements in a row,
